# The boundaries of acceptable typography for alphabet letters

Tags: writing-system, hebrew

I am wondering if there are any "modern" / "minimal" Hebrew fonts out there that demonstrate a different view of some of the letters. Specifically, I have seen quite a bit of variation in how the Aleph is written. For example, the first image below shows it as almost an `X`.

[image]

The same with the Lamed which is close to a `7`, and the Ayin a sort of `V` or `U`. But other more standard typographies use it differently, such as this:

[image]

That typecase has more flair to it, more curves, than the more sans-serif font above.

I have two questions. First, where I can learn the standard typographic structure for the alphabet in sans-serif such as like the [word project font](https://www.wordproject.org/bibles/he/01/1.htm). The second is how variable it is allowed to be in its structure. I am not sure if people have ever just written an Aleph ℵ as an X or an N or a Gimmel ג as a Lambda λ, or if it is important to have it the way it is.

[Here](https://heavenawaits.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/star-of-david-hebrew-letters.jpg) is another example of a very simple typography. And this is another highly variant one.

[image]

Comment: It may almost look like an X to you, but it's certainly not an X. Don't write א as an X, please. When writing, you should write in cursive. No one writes in block unless it's some special case. As for fonts, yes, there are many. The easiest would be to type something in Hebrew in MS Word and then try all the different Hebrew fonts. You will see all the subtle differences. Also, you can Google "Hebrew fonts" and find many sites with different font examples.

Comment: Please point me to a rule book on what I can and cannot do when writing either cursive or preferably in block. I have seen almost every font Google and MS Word offer in Hebrew, and places like [opensiddur](https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/), but still, don't know the rules for what a letter can and can't be, and would like to have some sort of (hopefully freely available online) reference.